# Re-implementing Social Logins (in Django)

Tags: django, oauth, google-oauth, facebook-oauth, python-social-auth

TL;DR: Is it OK to not store (Google/Facebook) OAuth2 access tokens, but rather request new ones on every login?

I'll explain:

To add social logins ("Login with Google/Facebook") to a Django app, you have [Python Social Auth](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django). The problem with it, at least for me, is that it's much more complicated than I'd like, requires a lot of configurations, creates additional tables in the database, and in general feels like a lot of moving parts I don't understand for a rather simple task.

So, I read a bit about [Google's](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) and [Facebook's](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/) flows, and they're simple enough:

- The server has an **ID** and a **secret**.
- The clients/users have their standard login credentials.

Then:

1. The server redirects the user to Google/Facebook, and provides its **ID** and a **redirection URI**.
2. After the user has logged in, Google/Facebook redirects them to that URI with a **code**.
3. The server sends its **ID**, **secret**, and the received **code** to Google/Facebook, and gets an **access token** in exchange, which it can now use to make API calls on behalf of the user.
4. Even the most basic permissions are enough to query Google/Facebook for the user's email, which can then be matched against Django's standard User model (and if it doesn't exist, a password-less user can created).

The access token can now be discarded, as it was only necessary to translate the Google/Facebook login to an actual email (validated by them), which is used as the *only* user identifier - no more confusion due to different accounts when logging via different social services; no additional tables; no unnecessary complexity.

Here's the code, just to show how little is necessary:

```
# views.py

def login_view(request):
    return render(request, 'login.html', {
        'google_url': 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?' + urllib.parse.urlencode({
            'client_id': GOOGLE_ID,
            'redirect_uri': request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('oauth_google')),
            'scope': 'profile email',
            'response_type': 'code',
        }),
    }) # use this url in the template as a social login

def oauth_google(request):
    code = request.GET['code']
    response = requests.post('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token', {
        'code': code,
        'client_id': GOOGLE_ID,
        'client_secret': GOOGLE_SECRET,
        'redirect_uri': request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('oauth_google')),
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
    }).json()
    id_token = response['id_token']
    response = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo', {
        'id_token': id_token,
    }).json()
    email = response['email']
    user = User.objects.filter(username=email).first()
    if not user:
        user = User(username=email)
        user.save()
    auth.login(request, user)
    return redirect('index')

# urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('oauth/google', views.oauth_google, name='oauth_google'),
]
```

My question is: what am I missing? If it's really that simple, why couldn't I find any answers on StackOverflow / tutorials on the web describing just that?

The only reason I can think of is that access tokens come with an expiration time (anywhere between 1 hour and 60 days); so maybe I'm supposed to keep reusing the same access token as long as it's valid (which will require storing it, and would explain why Python Social Auth needs additional tables). Will Google/Facebook get mad at me for requesting new access tokens too frequently and block me? I couldn't find any mention of this in their documentation.

**EDIT**

Here's the Facebook code, in case anyone finds these snippets useful:

```
# views.py

def login_view(request):
    return render(request, 'login.html', {
        'facebook_url': 'https://www.facebook.com/v3.2/dialog/oauth?' + urllib.parse.urlencode({
            'client_id': FACEBOOK_ID,
            'redirect_uri': request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('oauth_facebook')),
            'scope': 'email',
        }),
    }) # use this url in the template as a social login

def oauth_facebook(request):
    code = request.GET['code']
    response = requests.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/oauth/access_token', {
        'code': code,
        'client_id': FACEBOOK_ID,
        'client_secret': FACEBOOK_SECRET,
        'redirect_uri': request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('oauth_facebook')),
    }).json()
    access_token = response['access_token']
    response = requests.get('https://graph.facebook.com/me', {
        'access_token': access_token,
        'fields': 'email',
    }).json()
    email = response['email']
    user = User.objects.filter(username=email).first()
    if not user:
        user = User(username=email)
        user.save()
    auth.login(request, user)
    return redirect('index')

# urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('oauth/facebook', views.oauth_facebook, name='oauth_facebook'),
]
```